# How to check the health of the Elastic Search server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have download the elastic Search client Nest from the Nuget package manager.

and I am not able the recognize the function to check the health of the server.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

From NEST version of 7.X you need to use

```
client.Cluster.Health();
```

Comment: `.IsValid` to get a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

When elastic server was not connected green state returned, that is not correct in this case you must check response.IsValid
changed code is as below

```
    public string HealthCheck(WaitForStatus waitForStatus = WaitForStatus.Red, bool logResults = false)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        var client = new ElasticClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        var response = client.ClusterHealth(new ClusterHealthRequest() { WaitForStatus = waitForStatus });

        var healthColor = response.Status.ToString().ToLower();

        // this will give you the color code of the elastic search server health.
        if (response.IsValid)
        {
            switch (healthColor)
            {
                case "green":
                    message = "ElasticSearch Server health check returned [GREEN]";
                    break;

                case "yellow":
                    message = "ElasticSearch Server health check returned [YELLOW] (yellow is normal for single node clusters) ";
                    break;

                default: // Includes "red"
                    message = string.Format("ElasticSearch Server health check returned [{0}]", response.Status.ToString().ToUpper());
                    break;

            }
        }
        else
            message = response.ApiCall.OriginalException.Message;

        return message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the ElasticSearch.net and Nest both from the nuget package manager and both must be of the same versions.

here is the method to check the status using Nest Elastic Client.

```
 public string HealthCheck(WaitForStatus waitForStatus = WaitForStatus.Red, bool logResults = false)
   {
             var response = this._client.ClusterHealth(new ClusterHealthRequest() { WaitForStatus = waitForStatus });

             var healthColor = response.Status.ToLower();

            // this will give you the color code of the elastic search server health.

            switch (healthColor)
                    {
                        case "green":
                        var message = "ElasticSearch Server health check returned [GREEN]";
                       break;

                    case "yellow":
                        var message = "ElasticSearch Server health check returned [YELLOW] (yellow is normal for single node clusters) ";
                        break;

                    default: // Includes "red"
                        var message = "ElasticSearch Server health check returned [{0}]".FormatInLine(response.Status.ToUpper());
                        break;

                }

        return message;
   }
```

you can identify the health of the server by the message that you get.
Green and yellow are acceptable, red may causes some issues.

Thanks............